# How to check whether the given word can make up the word in R?

Tags: r

I am given a list of words :

```
words = c("is", "am", "are", "I", "He", "She", "toy", "jam", "kite", "playing", "eating")
```

and also a data frame of concentrated sentence, for example:

```
> example
  [,1]            
1 "Iamplayingkite"
2 "Itiseatingbone"
```

row 1 `Iamplayingkite`, are made up of all the words in the list, where row 2 `Itiseatingbone` is missing two words from the list (`It` and `bone`). I want a list that returned all the missing words, like `missing.word = c("It", "bone", ...etc)`

```
> dput(example)
structure(c("Iamplayingkite", "Itiseatingbone"), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2"), NULL))
```

Comment: so why cant the I in `it` be considered as `i`? How should the computer know that? This requires parsing from the dictionary first of all, ie NLP, you have to trin a corpus probably. For example `it i seating bone` or even `it I sea ting bone` I mean almost every word is an english word. Why go for `it is a ting bone`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to build a regex alternation containing all the substrings.  Then, use `gsub` to remove all substrings from the inputs, where they can be found.  Finally, retain only rows in your data frame whose word lengths *after* replacement are still greater than zero.

```
words <- c("is", "am", "are", "I", "He", "She", "toy", "jam", "kite", "playing", "eating")
regex <- paste0("(?:", paste(words, collapse="|"), ")")
example <- data.frame(word=c("Iamplayingkite", "Itiseatingbone"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
example[nchar(gsub(regex, "", example$word)) > 0,]

[1] "Itiseatingbone"
```

As for deducing that the "missing" words are `It` and `bone`, you can't easily do that without having some knowledge base which tells you that `It` and `bone` are even words.  Regex by itself cannot figure this out, not without some reference to go by.

Comment: when i apply to the actual data (basically a larger df), I got the error `Error in gsub(regex, "", example$word) : invalid regular expression`?

Comment: @MathAvengers I can't fix code which I can't see.  Maybe you should paste a demo link here.

Comment: I figure it out using a loop and some alternation of your code! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to at least get you on the right track.  Cheers.